# how to load extracted file name into sql server table in SSIS

Tags: ssis

i have 3 csv files in a folder which contains **eid, ename, country** fields, and my 5 csv files names are test1_20120116_034512, test1_20120116_035512,test1_20120116_035812 etc.. my requirement is I want to take lastest file based on timne stamp and modified date, which i have done. Now i want to import the extracted file name into destination table..

my destination tables contains fields like,

**filepath, filename, eid, ename, country**

I have posted regarding this before in the same site i got an answer for extracting filename, now i want to load the extracted FileName into destination table

- [Import most recent csv file to sql server in ssis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831060/import-most-recent-csv-file-to-sql-server-in-ssis)

my destination tables should have output as

**C:/source   test1_20120116_035812   1234   tester   USA**

Comment: Could you be a little more clear on the overall picture of the problem you are trying to solve. I can't really tell from your question but it seems like you have a recurring set of imports you need done on the same files on a regular basis. If this is true - I just finished a large project which required this on multiple sites (servers\physical locations) - I came up with a method that works very well but I approached it a bit differently than you seem to be doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your DataFlow task, add a Derived Column Transformation. The value of CurrentFile will be the fully qualified path to the file. As you only want the file name, I would look to use a replace function on that with the base folder and then strip the remaining slash. This does **not** strip the file extension but you can add yet another call to `REPLACE` and substitute an empty string

- Derived Column Name:  filename
- Derived Column:
- Expression:  `REPLACE(REPLACE(@[User::CurrentFile], @[User::RootFolder], ""), "\\", "")`

The above expects it to look like

- CurrentFile = "C:\source\test1_20120116_035812.csv"
- RootFolder = "C:\source"

### Edit

I believe you've done something in your approach that I did not do. You *should* see a warning about possible truncation but given the values discussed in this and the preceding question, I don't believe the 4k limit on expressions will be of concern.

Displaying the derived column

[image: Derived columns]

Demonstrating the derived column does work

[image: Data flow via derived column]

I will give you a +1 for providing an approach I wasn't aware of, but you'll still need to add a derived column to match your provided format (base path name)

[image: Flat File custom properties]

Full path is provided from the custom properties. Use the above REPLACE section to remove the path info except use the column `[FileName]` instead of `@[User::CurrentFile]`

[image: Full path provided]

Comment: HI Billinkc, I tried to use the expression which u have given, whn running the package its throwing an error like <b>[Derived Column [89]] Error: The "component "Derived Column" (89)" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "output column "filename" (189)" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.</b>..

Comment: I've updated my answer with pictures. The derived column does work based on my understanding of your environment.

Comment: How can I use your code to work with mine? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22969449/how-to-use-the-latest-file-in-a-folder-for-source

Comment: Downvoter, if you could provide some feedback on what is unhelpful or unclear about this answer, the community would appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

I tried to get the filename through the procedure which Billinkc has given, but its throwing me error stating that filename column failed becaue of truncation error..

Any how i tried different approach to load file name into table.

**steps i have used**
1. right click on flat file Source and click on show advanced edito for Flat file
2. select component Properties tab
3. Inside that Custom Properties section --->  it has a property **FileNameColumnName**
I have assigned Filename to that column property like

**FileNameColumnName----> FileName** thats it, am able to get the filename into my destination table..

Comment: Based on the samples provided, this does not address removing the path information.