# Using SSIS Expression Builder to Retrieve File with the oldest datetime?

Tags: c#, ssis

I have a Holding directory with files in it that are downloaded from FTP throughout the day.

At any time I need to be able to sort the collection and retrieve the file whose CreationTime attribute is the oldest. This file will then be moved from "Holding" to "Pending".

Since I am using an SSIS package to move the file using a System File Task, I need to manipulate an expression based on the CreationDate variable. Trouble is, I am really unfamiliar with this "expression" language you are faced with using in the Expression Builder.

So, how would I retrieve a file whose creation date is the oldest using an expression script?

Or is there an easier way to do what I want to do with a Script Task?

Comment: Dupe/check out my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831060/import-most-recent-csv-file-to-sql-server-in-ssis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to loop trough the files on a script task and inside this script check the last created,  load its name to a global variable and then use it on your System File Task

this may help you: `http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/adding-the-script-task-to-your-ssis-packages/`

Comment: Would it be at all possible to load a dbml into the script task solution and use linq to sort the collection?

Comment: apparently you can (had to google it) but I never did it. If you can accomplish it, it would remove the necessity for the loop. great Idea. Let me know if you were able to

Comment: Good Deal. I appreciate the help, Diego.