# finding latest excel file from folder using ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have group of excel files in a folder. excel file name will be like

```
ABC 2014-09-13.xlsx
ABC 2014-09-14.xlsx
ABC 2014-09-15.xlsx
```

I need to get the data from latest excel file and load it into the table using `ssis` package.

Comment: here is duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831060/import-most-recent-csv-file-to-sql-server-in-ssis

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the shortest answer, but will help you.

Steps:

1. Create a `For-each loop`, to fetch all the `excel sheets`. Insert all the excel sheet names to a `table`.
2. Create a **variable**. Assign its value as the `MAX()` among Excel dates.
3. Add a 2nd `Fore-each loop`. Just like the 1st loop, pick all the excel sheets 1 by 1, compare each file name with Variable value. Load the excel which matches it.

Answer (score 0):

As this is duplicate question, I will put answer anyway with some changes or additional info.

1. You should have created table for excel to import and added **Connection Manager** into package.
2. Create 2 variables **MainDir**, where excel files exists, and **ExcelFile** to hold last file full name.
3. Add **Script Task** to package. Open it and in the Script tab add `ReadOnlyVariables = User::MainDir` and `ReadWriteVariables = User::ExcelFile`
4. Press Edit Script... button and in the new window paste this code:

into Main

```
 string fileMask = "*.xlsx";
 string mostRecentFile = string.Empty;
 string rootFolder = string.Empty;

 rootFolder = Dts.Variables["User::MainDir"].Value.ToString();     
 System.IO.DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(rootFolder);     
 System.IO.FileInfo mostRecent = null;

 System.IO.FileInfo[] legacyArray = directoryInfo.GetFiles(fileMask, System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);    
 Array.Sort(legacyArray, (f2, f1) => f2.Name.CompareTo(f1.Name));

 mostRecent = legacyArray[legacyArray.Length - 1];

 if (mostRecent != null)
 {
      mostRecentFile = mostRecent.FullName;
 }

 Dts.Variables["User::ExcelFile"].Value = mostRecentFile;
 Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;`
```

5. Create **Excel Connection Manager** and in the Edit mode select Excel file path to some excel, Excel version and if needed keep First row has column names checked.
6. In the properties of **Excel Connection Manager** find Expressions and add Property **ExcelFilePath** with value `@[User::ExcelFile]`
7. Put Data Flow Task, connect with Script task.
8. Add Excel Source into Data Flow Task. Open editor. Select `Excel Connection Manager` you created before, `Data access mode` change to SQL command and add this line (make sure, that excel file sheet name is Sheet1): `SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]`. Also check if all necessary columns selected in Columns tab.
9. The last component is **OLE DB Destination**, which you must connect with Excel Source component. Add connection manager, select table and mappings to table you want to insert.

That's all you need to do to insert excel...