# C# MVC upload CSV file & import it to SQL server by creating table dynamically

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a requirement where we need to import data from a .csv file to SQL server by creating the table dynamically. The reason for dynamic table creation is because the .csv file will have columns changing. We have to drop the existing table & recreate a new table based on the header information in the .csv file. (user may be running some diagnostic queries on that table later on)

I'm using C#.net MVC-3 & SQL Server 2014 standard version.Please let me know the best possible ways of achieving this.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you are using the right tools. Check this question out. It might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831060/import-most-recent-csv-file-to-sql-server-in-ssis

Comment: Does the CSV file contain a header row?  Some information is needed to name the columns.

Comment: yes, it does. The .csv file is generated by executing a standard perfmon job on any windows machine.