# SSIS -Need to Load the latest file to sql server using the C# scripts

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis-2008

I need to load the data from the latest file to SQL Server, I have to handle this in the SSIS using C# script. I am not good in C# scripting. We are using 2010 version.

```
ACCOUNT_20170703_030505.txt
ACCOUNT_20170703_022510.txt
ACCOUNT_20170703_060015.txt
```

Can you kindly help me how to fetch the latest file name in script and pass to SSIS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please add more information, maybe code or screen shoot will help to improve the question and people will help you, thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you need a [tutorial](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-introducing-the-foreach-loop-container/) rather than an answer, which is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I think your query can be resolved by solution provided in below article link:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831060/import-most-recent-csv-file-to-sql-server-in-ssis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831060/import-most-recent-csv-file-to-sql-server-in-ssis)

Comment: I have different set files in the folder like below, ACCOUNT_20170703_030505.txt
ACCOUNT_20170703_022510.txt
ACCOUNT_20170703_060015.txt
BANK_20160502_030441.txt
CHECK_20170215_091000.txt ..... I want to read the latest file of the ACCOUNT and load into the DB.  I mean the file ACCOUNT_20170703_060015.txt is the latest because it created on 3rd July 2017 6 AM . So I want to get this filename dynamic by checking the file name in SSIS using SCRIPT TASK (using C# coding). Is it possible.